# Need help creating multiple return statements in a java methood

Tags: java, variables, return

I'm a freshmen at college and I'm starting with my first Java programming course. The professor sent us an assignment in order to make an application simulating the database of the USPS.

Anyways, I got to the point where I want my program to ask line by line for the recipients information (address, name, city etc) and I managed to do so using a simple JOptionPane. The problem is that now, I'm using Java methods and I can't for the life of me figure out how to make the return statement so my program moves on to the next method, with my recipients information.

```
private static String getString(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String nameString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Recipients name:", "Certified Mail Receipt", 3);

    String streetAddressString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Street, Apt. No. or P.O. Box No.:", "Certified Mail Receipt",
            3);

    String cityString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "City, State, Zip Code", "Certified Mail Receipt", 3);
    // return ?????????`
}
```

The compiler will only let me insert one return statement and only one of the 3 questions gets sent to the next methood. I think I need a way to get the three things in a return statement so the program stops asking the same recipients information questions over and over again.

I'm using the Eclipse Java compiler if that helps. Thanks!

======================EDIT================================ 
@TerryLi helped me by finding an error in my class

```
private static String getString(String type) {
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
        type, 
        "Certified Mail Receipt", 
        3);
return result;
```

}

This is how I manged to get it to work. again thanks to @terryli and everyone who helped out with a reply!

Comment: You could use global variables

Comment: @FlorisVelleman - come on, hes a learning developer, please don't teach him bad habits right out of the gate.

Comment: You could create a data structure which holds all return values you need.

Comment: @Perception I found them very usefull when I started off in Java. But I get the point :)

Comment: @Perception: May be Floris Velleman mentioned private variables?

Comment: I suggest that you start by describing *in words* what is the purpose of the `getString()` method. What is it *supposed* to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me provide an alternative:

```
String splitter = "-.-";
return nameString+splitter+streetAddressString+splitter+cityString;
```

We can retrieve the return values as follows:

```
String returns = getString(...);
String nameString = returns.split(splitter)[0];
String streetAddressString = returns.split(splitter)[1];
String cityString = returns.split(splitter)[2];
```

And this would be the only workaround in case you want to keep the method signature the same.

**Edit**:

Given that you are new to Java, try the following code:

```
return nameString+"-.-"+streetAddressString+"-.-"+cityString;
```

Basically, I just removed the global variable `splitter` to make it simple for you.

```
String nameString = returns.split("-.-")[0];
String streetAddressString = returns.split("-.-")[1];
String cityString = returns.split("-.-")[2];
```

**Update**:

You only need to modify the `getString` method as follows:

```
private static String getString(String type) {
    String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            type, 
            "Certified Mail Receipt", 
            3);
    return result;   
}
```

This should solve your problem. Let me know.

`Update2`:

```
private static void showReceipt(double postage, double certifiedFee,
        double restrictedFee, double returnReceiptFee, String nameString,
        String addressString, String cityString) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat(" $0.00");
    double certifiedMailFee = 0;
    double restrictedDelivery = 0;
    String outputString = "U.S. POSTAL SERVICE\nCERTIFIED MAIL RECEIPT\n---------------------\nPostage" + 
            fmt.format(postage) + 
            "\nCertified Mail Fee" + fmt.format(certifiedMailFee) + 
            "\nRestricted Delivery Fee" + fmt.format(restrictedDelivery) + 
            "\nReturn Receipt Fee" + fmt.format(returnReceiptFee) + 
            "\nTotal Postage & Fees" + fmt.format(postage + certifiedMailFee + restrictedDelivery + returnReceiptFee) + 
            "\n----------------------------" + 
            "\nSend to:" + 
            "\n" + nameString + 
            "\n----------------------------" + 
            "\nStreet, Apt No., or PO Box No." + 
            "\n" + addressString + 
            "\n----------------------------" + 
            "\nCity, State, ZIP+4®" + 
            "\n" + cityString;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            outputString, 
            "Certified Mail Receipt", 
            1, 
            null);

}
```

Hopefully, you will notice the change I just made to the code above.

Comment: The downside is the users evil input here.

Comment: Where would I insert this into my program If I were going with this methood? I inserted the first part of the code and didn't encounter any errors but I do not know where to insert the return values you provided below. Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: @GabrielOFigueroa Assume we have got the string returned from your method, let's assign the value to `returns`. Then we split the string `returns` into three parts using `returns.split("-.-")`. Finally, you can use the subscript or array index to retrieve each of three parts, as shown in the code above.

Comment: @GabrielOFigueroa You don't need to insert the return values anywhere until you need to retrieve and use them.

Comment: @TerryLi I'm still lost, sorry for being the newbies :$ The information is getting through, the problem is that in the code I posted, those questions are being asked 3 times in a row before I can get to the next methood. I would like for my program to ask for them once. thanks for all of the help and sorry for the trouble :/

Comment: @GabrielOFigueroa You meant the `getString` method would be invoked three times in a row?

Comment: @GabrielOFigueroa If you could point us to the description of your assignment, that would help us understand the whole problem.

Comment: No, I mean that when I run the program as a jar its supposed to ask: Name>Street>City and then move on to the next window. it asks Name>Street>City 3 times before moving onto the next methood @TerryLi Thank You!

Comment: @GabrielOFigueroa Can you post the entire program you've got so far? That way I can identify what you didn't get right more quickly.

Comment: I will in a bit, I had to run some errands you can also talk w/ me through gmail I'm gabrielomar1 or kik gab2012 thanks @TerryLi

Comment: It Worked! You won't believe how grateful I am for your help @TerryLi One question, when I pass onto the end of the program theres one of the answers that comes up as null. any info on that? Thank you so much! Its the City and Zip code section

Comment: I see you removed String streetAddressString = null; and changed the streetAddressString to addressString. I figure it was a mistyped variable on my part :$ Thank you very much and sorry for all the trouble @TerryLi you've taught me a few tricks on how to get started, hopefully they wont be the last!

Answer (score 7):

Write a wrapper class that holds the data:

```
public class SomeWrapper
{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String city;

    public SomeWrapper(String n, String a, String c)
    {
        name = n;
        address = a;
        city = c;
    }

    public String getAddress(){return address;}
    public String getName(){return name;}
    public String getCity(){return city;}
}
```

Then use it like:

```
private static String getData()
{
   // ...

   SomeWrapper w = new SomeWrapper(nameString, streetAddressString, cityString);

   return w;
}
```

and extract it like this:

```
SomeWrapper w = getData();
String nameString = w.getName();
String streetAddressString = w.getAddress();
String cityString = w.getCity();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, I'm really new to all of this and I started this program in my class yesterday with guidance from my professor. I'm still reading you replies carefully and trying to understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array or static variables outside this method. 
a method can easily returns array of string that containt all the three strings you hava been prompted

Answer (score 0):

Two ways.

1. Use Global Varaibles

   **

   **

**

```
private static String nameString, streetAddressString, cityString;
        private static String getString(String string) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            nameString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Recipients name:", "Certified Mail Receipt", 3);

            streetAddressString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Street, Apt. No. or P.O. Box No.:", "Certified Mail Receipt",
                    3);

            cityString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "City, State, Zip Code", "Certified Mail Receipt", 3);
            //No need to return, they are available globally 
        }
```

**

**

**

OR, Pass them as method parameters

**

```
private static String getString(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String nameString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Recipients name:", "Certified Mail Receipt", 3);
    String streetAddressString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Street, Apt. No. or P.O. Box No.:", "Certified Mail Receipt",
            3);
    String cityString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "City, State, Zip Code", "Certified Mail Receipt", 3);

stringMethod(nameString,streetAddressString,cityString);
}
```

**

Answer (score 0):

The Java programming language doesn't allow to return multiple variables. But you can return objects, most precisely, you can return a reference to an object. So, if you want to return multiple things, just create a data structure (class) that fits all of your requirements, and return a instance of it.

E.g.:

```
public class DataStruct{

    public DataStruct(String nameString, String streetAddressString, String cityString){
         this.nameString = nameString;
         this.streetAddressString = streetAddressString;
         this.cityString = cityString;
    }

    public String nameString;
    public String streetAddressString;
    public String cityString;
}

private static String getString(String string) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String nameString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Recipients name:", "Certified Mail Receipt", 3);

String streetAddressString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Street, Apt. No. or P.O. Box No.:", "Certified Mail Receipt",
        3);

String cityString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "City, State, Zip Code", "Certified Mail Receipt", 3);
return new DataStruct(nameString,streetAddressString,cityString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion you have two obvious options, depending on how you wanna use the strings afterwards. The way I see it, you could either return a concatenated string that returns all the information from all the variables, which would be made like this in your case:

```
/* The \n just puts each peace of info on a new line you could just do a 
" " instead or something. */
return nameString+"\n"+streetAddressString+"\n"+cityString;
```

Or you could return a stringarray with each string in a certain place(index):

```
String[] stringList = new String[3];
```

And read them into the array and return the array (don't forget to change the return type if you do this).

```
/* index in arrays start at 0 so its always 1 less than the size you make it 
(if you didnt know) */
stringList[0] = nameString;
stringList.... etc.
```

Also you should know that getters are usually public classes, you simply make the field values private and get them with the getters. (as standard practice and as far as I know anyways).
Hope it helps.

EDIT: In my opinion using static variables when it's not even necessary, is a very bad idea. If you can solve the problem without it, do it that way instead.

Comment: Hi Obed, your first return statement worked! but when I run my program, after asking me for the information (the three promts) It keeps asking me the same questions a few times before actually taking me to the final step which shows all of the information in one place. I'm missing something but I'm not sure what it is :/

Answer (score 0):

Java won't allow you to return multiple values unless you use either an array or a wrapper class or structure of some kind. Since both those approaches have been covered already, I would suggest the alternative of splitting it up into a few different methods to make it more readable.

```
private static String promptForString(String message, String title)
{
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,message,title,3);
}

private static String promptForName()
{
    return promptForString("Recipients name:","Certified Mail Receipt");
}

private static String promptForStreetAddress()
{
    return promptForString("Street, Apt. No. or P.O. Box No.:","Certified Mail Receipt");
}

private static String promptForCity()
{
    return promptForString("City, State, Zip Code","Certified Mail Receipt");
}
```

then in your caller method you could simply use

```
String name = promptForName();
String streetAddress = promptForStreetAddress();
String city = promptForCity();
```

This has the added advantage of allowing you to add more fields fairly easily or using the promptForString method for something else altogether.